# How to establish web service to .net platform from android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

I want to connect .net platform from android and also get the data from the data base.please help me to move forward.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although you have accepted an answer, this question is too vague. Try to elaborate more in your next questions and also show some research effort. It will help you getting positive votes in your questions as well as more people to help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use xml parser like `kSoub`,`SAX-Parser`, or you can use `JSON`. Just google example. You need to create .net `webservice`, These web-service you need to access using above any method.